# Changing Label for Generic PC in Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco-ios, packet-tracer

I can change easily *Router* and *Switch* names in Packet Tracer using `hostname` command in `global config mode`. But how could I change a label of a Generic PC, let's say from **PC0** to **Sales**? i could not find one. I know there should be a way since I saw some Cisco Packet tracer example files that has different labels for their PCs.

I am using by the way **Cisco Packet Tracer 6.3** for your information.

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so, you should accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: No it did not. I have to use Win 7 in order to do the configuration but not on Win 10.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Single click on the computer's name.  A text box might pop up (worked intermittently for me in 6.2) where you can input a new name.
2. Click on the computer, go to Config, and change the display name.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not see the **Config** tab on my `Windows 10`. But on my other computer running `Windows 7`, I was able to see the Config tab and could change the label. However, my current working computer (which is a laptop) is running on `Windows 10` and the `Windows 7` computer that I mentioned about is a PC which I don't have access all the time. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

If the Config tab is not showing up, in the top toolbar go to Options > Preferences > Hide, and make sure "Hide Config Tab is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the command "set pcname"